# Cache Busting in Leaflet marker popups

Tags: javascript, caching, leaflet

I'm using a Leaflet map with popups which load updating images. However the images end up cacheing. I thought I'd fix this by adding Date.now() but this only adds the date when the page loads rather than when the pop up opens.

```
.bindPopup('<img src="image.jpg?'+ Date.now()+'" width="260" height="196" border="0"><br>Location One').addTo(map),
```

I've tried putting the date now in a separate function...

```
function foo () {
setInterval(Date.now(), 10000)
}
```

and calling that function from the pop up:

```
   .bindPopup('<img src="image.jpg?'+ foo() +'" width="260" height="196" border="0"><br>Location One').addTo(map),
```

however that just loads: "image.jpg?undefined".

How can I get the cache busting timestamp to update?

(At the moment I'm just using a meta refresh to update the whole page which isn't very elegant and reloads the page just when you've got to the location on the map you want...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could bind an arbitrary container / empty content to the popup and instead listen for the `popupopen` event on the relevant *Map*, *Marker* or *Path*.

```js
scope.on('popupopen', function(ev){
    var src = 'image.jpg?v=' + Date.now();
    ev.popup.setContent('<img src="'+ src +'"/>');
});
```

Comment: I couldn't get your exact answer to work right (It may have been something I did wrong when trying to scale it to work with the several hundred markers I've got). But I've made use of the popupopen function which I didn't know about. 

So I've given the image an ID and adapted some jquery I've used elsewhere:

    map.on('popupopen', function(e) {
    $('#popupimage').attr('src', $('#popupimage').attr('src') + '?' + Date.now() )
    });